# How do I link my react native website to my app?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm creating a banking platform and I would like to link the react native website to the RN app so that all of the contents that are stored on the website will be shown on the app and vice versa. I'm not sure about the dependencies/code I will need to do it, so I don't have any sample code. Can someone please show me how to link my app to my website?

Comment: What do you mean by "react native website"? Do you mean you want to show your website inside your react native app?

Comment: I think more details are needed here, what do you mean by 'contents'?  Are you talking about a backend/database?

Comment: @DarkMatter I want to show what's posted on my website on my app too. For example, youtube.com is able to store data and show it on their app and their app can do the same vice versa. I want to be able to save the data on my website and post it on my app, and also post my app data to my website

Comment: @Abe Like youtube.com. I want to show what's on my website on my app too

Comment: react-native-webview?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this. Here are two of them -

1. Create APIs for your website. In your app, use these APIs to fetch the content of your website. This method will require some extra work.
2. Use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) to display your website directly inside your app. In this case, your website should be mobile-friendly for a better user experience. [Here's one popular webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) package for React Native.